# Is Yitroh's judicial structure mentioned anywhere else in the Tanakh?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, beit-din-court, parashas-yisro

Yitro advised to divide the people into groups of 10, 50, 100,1000 and appoint a corresponding judge for every group.

Is the legal process of any of such judges mentioned in the Tanakh? I mean, does it say that X, the head of 100, or 1000 (for example) held a sentence and convicted someone of something?

Comment: The Torah in Parshas Shoftim instructs Jews to organize courts by city. I always assumed that Yisro's advice was only for while they were in the Midbar. The Torah makes it pretty clear that the purpose was to help Moshe.

Answer (score 2):

No such legal process is mentioned in Tanach. The words שר(י) עשרה/חמשים/מאות/אלפים appear again outside of Torah, but not with reference to the division from the desert. The verses are:

Samuel 1:8:12 — Samuel saying what the king will do;
Samuel 1:18:13 — Saul making David a military commander;
Samuel 1:22:7 — Saul incredulously asking whether David has promoted these people;
Samuel 2:18:1 — David promoting military leaders;
Kings 2:1:9, 11, 13 — captains of the groups that get sent to Eliyahu;
Isaiah 3:3 — reproach to the leaders (including the captains of 50);
Chronicles 2:17:14 — list of military leaders.

Comment: And what does this have to do with civil courts? You should state your claim more clearly.

Comment: Absolutely nothing: that's the point. The words are mentioned but *not* referring to the divisions from Yitro. I'm not sure how much clearer I can be than `The words... appear again outside of Torah, but not with reference to the division from the desert.`

Comment: Oh, right, thank you +1